# Amazon RDS (Relational Data Store) and SSIS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, amazon-rds

Does anyone know if it is possibble to use SSIS with Amazon RDS?
Since RDS is essentially MySQL - would this be possible using OLE DB or something...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon RDS offers complete support for all MySQL features except for replication. Therefore you can use OLE DB, or any other driver, to access MySQL from your application.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use MySQL ODBC driver in combination with ADO.NET Source component. The ODBC provider is the most stable.